# How to define two functions in a clear and standard way?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, proof-writing

I am working on a question and before I ask it, I wanted to get help in defining two functions clearly in a standard way.

Here are the two functions:

$f(a,x,p)$:  count of the number of pairs $k,k+2$ such that $k \ge x$ and $k+2 < 30a + x$ and $\gcd(k^2+2k,p\#) = 1$ where $p\#$ is the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) for prime $p$.

Example:

$f(1,2,5) = 3$ since $(\{11,13\}, \{17,19\},\{29,31\})$ satisfy this condition.

$g(a,b,x,p)$: if we compare $f(a,x,p), f(a,x+30a,p), f(a,x+60a,p), \dots, f(a,x+30(b-1)a,p)$, what is the value for the lowest $f(a,x+30j,p)$ where $0 \le j < b$

Example:

$g(1,7,2,7) = 1$ since the lowest value is at $f(1,62,7)=1$ since the $\{71,73\}$ are the values that satisfy the condition and $0 \le 2 < 7$

Are these functions clear? Any suggestions on improving their definition?

How would a professional mathematician define these two functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear. My suggestion is to also write them mathematically, as this will be more concise. In the following, $|A|$ denotes the size of the set $A$.

$$f(a,x,p) = \left|\{(k,k+2)\in\mathbb{Z}^2\ |\ k\geq x,\ k+2\leq 30a+x,\ \gcd(k^2+2k,p\#) = 1\}\right|,$$

and

$$g(a,b,x,p) = \min_{0\leq j<b,\ j\in\mathbb{N}} f(a,x+30j,p).$$

Comment: Thanks very much!  I wanted to write both functions more concisely.